# Is it possible to find the child body involved in a collision of a compound shape?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bullet-physics

I am noob at using bullet physics. I am using it for collison detection and I want to create a compound body to represent a ship. However, in my game I need to know which part of the ship was hit.

The contact manifolds only have the collision objects in other words the compound body. The contact manifold does not have the child body that collided.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to give each part a different rigid body / collision shape. They were then connected using constrains, and collisions between constrained bodies were disabled. I disabled the collisions using btDynamicsWorld::addConstraint(btTypedConstraint* constraint, bool disableCollisionsBetweenLinkedBodies)